# Angular default app not displaying in browser

Tags: angular, webpack

I am trying to learn Angular. I created my first angular app earlier today. Then I ran,
`npx ng serve` to display the app in the browser. I prefixed the command with `npx` because it is installed locally. It said it compiled successfully. Then I went to http://localhost:4200/ and I saw nothing. However, the page metadata such as the favicon loaded. When I opened the console I saw all of these errors:

[image]

Has anyone else experienced this or does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Did you generate the project using **ng new**? And without any changes did it run?

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

I created a new angular app and it rendered.